# How to create a custom config file and get data using inline JS in a wordpress page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm totally new in WordPress as well as in PHP and making my first application with it.

Currently, I use *'HTML block Element'*  to add content with custom HTML and inline Javascript code on blank WordPress pages (using Elementor). I want to create a new config file(or add data on an existing one) on which I can define some variables which I then will be getting using Js and work accordingly.

I tried adding defines in the wp-config file and accessing them with Js but it didn't work.

**wp-config**

```
define('PERSONAL_KEY', 'VALUE');
```

In custom HTML code element of WP Page

```
<script>   
   var data = "<?php echo PERSONAL_KEY; ?>";
   // Didn't worked
</script>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Works fine for me. can you show the full code where use it?

Comment: @Bhautik I tried printing it on console but it just prints `<?php echo PERSONAL_KEY; ?>`

Comment: does your file is PHP or HTML?

Comment: @Bhautik code is in html block inside a blank wordpress page (I'm using Elementor)

Comment: so you use element?

Comment: @Bhautik yes html element to add html and inline JS code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230961/discussion-between-bhautik-and-aditya).